# Zuul Proxy HTTPS Forwarding Error

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul

I am facing a problem when trying to use Zuul, As the client apps are registered in Eureka using HTTPS, when Zuul reads from Eureka registries it receive the url with no HTTPS and Zuul can't point to the right url (Https url).

Maybe some of you had faced this problem. 
Thank you for help.

**UPDATED**

Just to mention, I could solve the problem with the help of @RaphSoft, A team mate of the place where I work.

If someone is facing the same problem, He has posted the solution in his GitHub Repo, Here is the link. 
https://github.com/raphsoft/samples/tree/master/resource-server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a section in the user guide on that: http://projects.spring.io/spring-cloud/spring-cloud.html#_registering_a_secure_application. It's not in older versions of the guide but the feature is the same in older versions of the software. Summary: you need to set two flags in the `EurekaInstanceConfig`, viz `eureka.instance.[nonSecurePortEnabled,securePortEnabled]` and also, if you want to use Eureka to discover the health and info URLs, you also need to specify those explicitly, i.e. `eureka.instance.[healthCheckUrl,statusPageUrl]`.

You can also refer to the Netflix OSS wiki for more information on Eureka.

Comment: I am not sure what is EurekaInstanceConfig, please could you provide me an example, where do I have to set those properties? What is EurekaInstanceConfig in the documentacion just says enable those properties but there are not examples. Thank you very much.

Comment: Those properties are normal Spring Boot properties. You put the "spring-cloud" tag on your question, so I presume that is going to be what you need. If it is, then read the docs a bit about Spring Boot and Spring Cloud. If it isn't then read them anyway because it will make things easier.